# Paypal IPN always "INVALID" - charset related?

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've read a hundred discussions on this and none have helped so far.

I'm using the Sandbox, and after much head scratching I figured out that the character encoding settings in the Sandbox profile don't actually do anything (which is really stupid, for the record), so I've been trying to find another way to do it. I only have a limited understanding of how character encoding is handled in this situation, so I'm looking for some bulletproof code samples and/or explanations that will help.

I recieve the IPN request and the charset parameter is windows-1252, while the charset set in the header of my site is UTF8. I'm using the sample script Paypal provide (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/) with no alterations except using the Sandbox URL in the cURL request, and I'm always recieving invalid.

Paypals docs are useless and nothing I've found through Google has helped at all, so can someone please tell me why this is falling over?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the issue? What you are not able to do? Are you submitting a cart?

Comment: No it's just a "Buy Now" button, one item. I've just fixed the problem thanks to this page --> https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/926/ <-- which isn't mentioned anywhere in the sample code or documentation. Thanks for that Paypal.

Comment: Ben, I have the same problem, could you please answer yourself to your question and posting the full code ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, the problem is in using the `urldecode` and `urlencode` functions as opposed to `rawurlencode` and `rawurldecode`. If you remove the date value from the request (set it to null, for example), things should work because it probably has a timezone identifier in there (like `+0100 GMT`). The `+` symbol is getting interpreted as a space when using the default `urldecode` and `urlencode` functions, which results in a slightly altered request being sent back for verification, and hence an INVALID return.

Described in more detail [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-solution-to-paypal-ipn-always-returning-invalid).